# Disable innodb_file_per_table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have 24GB RAM i7 dedicated server, running CPanel 11.36 with MySQL 5.1.68. In my.cnf I have innodb_file_per_table enabled. Is it safe to just disable the option, not doing any damage to databases in the meantime after MySQL restarts?

Comment: Can you paste in your my.cnf file? InnoDB performance can be dramatically altered based on settings in here.  Also, are you using the built-in InnoDB or the [InnoDB plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replacing-builtin-innodb.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling innodb_file_per_table affects only newly created tables, so it is safe to turn it off or on at any time. Why do you want to turn it off?

Comment: I am having performance issues with the server (caused by MYSQL) and I can't pinpoint the cause. I have the impression that enabled innodb_file_per_table is more CPU intensive.

The server has only 6 low-traffic websites, but one of them (a Joomla 3.1 200MB db site) seems to have enormous impact on the box. I am trying various configurations.

Comment: I don't think that innodb_file_per_table is the cause for your performance issue. Nevertheless you can give it a try. Can you identify a bad performing query?

Comment: I have enabled slow query log but I have no record (yet).

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the option is fine. What will happen is any new tables agoing forward will be created in the shared tablespace instead of in it's own file.

However, there is almost no good reason to disable this option. Having the tables in their own file gives you lots of good with almost zero bad. By switching the feature off, you loose all of that good.